# PowerShell Form, how to refresh Label?

Tags: forms, powershell, label, refresh

I am playing around with forms and am stuck with refreshing information in a  Label.

Trying to refresh either Label or The Form itself did not work.
*The Testcode I wrote:*

```
CLS

Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$Counter = 1

$Main_Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Main_Form.Icon = $objIcon
$Main_Form.Text ='Test Test Test'
$Main_Form.Size = '1000,400'
$Main_Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Main_Form.AutoSize = $true
$Main_Form.BringToFront()
Test

Function Test {
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$Label.Location = '10,20'
$Label.Size = '200,60'
$Label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",16,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Label.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Label.ForeColor = "Blue"
$Label.Text = 'Counter '+$Counter
$Main_Form.Controls.Add($Label)

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = '50,200'
$Button.Size = '200,75'
$Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",16,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Button.Text = 'Next'
$Main_form.Controls.Add($Button)
$ButtonClickEvent = ({Write-Host 'Test '$Counter;$Global:Counter++})
$Button.Add_Click($ButtonClickEvent)
}

$Main_Form.ShowDialog()
```

When running the code, a window opens and it says Counter 1. Pressing the "Next" button, I would like the Counter to change to Number 2.

For testing purpose, I write Test 1 with adding "+1" each time, when Next is pressed and that seams to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for any help,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure why you had a test function there, but this will accomplish what you are after.

You need to add the `$Label.Text` to the `$ButtonClickEvent`.

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$Script:Counter = 1

$Main_Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Main_Form.Icon = $objIcon
$Main_Form.Text ='Test Test Test'
$Main_Form.Size = '1000,400'
$Main_Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Main_Form.AutoSize = $true
$Main_Form.BringToFront()

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$Label.Location = '10,20'
$Label.Size = '200,60'
$Label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",16,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Label.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Label.ForeColor = "Blue"
$Label.Text = 'Counter '+$Script:Counter
$Main_Form.Controls.Add($Label)

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = '50,200'
$Button.Size = '200,75'
$Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",16,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Button.Text = 'Next'
$Main_form.Controls.Add($Button)
$ButtonClickEvent = {
    Write-Host 'Test '$Script:Counter
    $Script:Counter++
    $Label.Text = "Counter $Script:Counter"
}
$Button.Add_Click($ButtonClickEvent)

$Main_Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Wow Drew,
Thanx a lot, that is the solution. Yes, sorry, was playing around and tried so much and also had the function in it. Forgotten to take it out.

Now it runs perfectly,
Again THANX